# Checking a file or directory (with spaces) exists in ksh

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I have to delete list of directories. The list is being read from a text file. The absolute path of the directory might contain spaces as well.
Here is what I am doing...

```
while read line # Each line is absolute path which might contain spaces
do
    var1=\"${line}\"
    if [ -d $var1 ]
    then
        rm -rf $var1
        rc=$?

        if [ $rc -ne 0 ]
        then
            echo "Remove failed for directory : $var1"
        fi
    else
        echo "Invalid input directory : $var1"
    fi
done < ${LIST}
```

This is not working. I also tried to execute the below code from the command line

```
line=/home/cg/root/3056488/test
var1=\"${line}\"
echo ${var1} # prints "/home/cg/root/3056488/test"
if [ -d ${var1} ]; then echo "success"; else echo "failure"; fi
```

But it is failing. How do I check if a file or directory (with spaces) exists in KSH?

Comment: `if [ -d "${line}" ]`?

Comment: No, not working. Tried that as well.

Comment: `\"` forces a *literal* double quote into the variable's value. You want to quote the variable,  not add random characters to its actual value.